# What will be printed in python

Tags: python, printing

```
for x in ("ab","cd"):
    print(x)
    print(x)
```

Second code:

```
X = 3
def ResetH(NewH)
    x= NewH
ResetH(5)
print("x is", x)
```

Third code:

```
 Tags=["ad","cd","Ef","gh"]
 print(tags[1])
```

All I want to know is what will be printed out in all codes.Not on a computer right now so I can't run it.

Comment: Python and it was posted weird but it should be on two lines like                          For x in ("ab","cd")                                                                                                         print(x)                                                                                                                   print(x)                                I just want to see what's printed out and the print stammers are in the for.

Comment: Jakub. Just did.

Comment: Just run the programs?

Comment: I'm not on a computer ATM otherwise I would.

Comment: Why is this so urgent that you can't wait until you have access to a computer?

Comment: It's for my homework but my computer is a t-rex and I think I got the correct code I just want to see it print.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using a browser though? You could go to [https://repl.it/](https://repl.it/) and start a Python environment.

Comment: I'm concerned that you're willing to submit homework that you *haven't run*, regardless of what answers you get here. *Always* check the results of the **exact code** you submit, and that includes not re-typing from (I presume) a phone.

Comment: Martin Evans thank you. I was using my phone and it worked like a gem

Answer (score 0):

for x in ("ab","cd"):
        print(x)
        print(x)

prints:

```
ab
ab
cd
cd
```

---

```
X = 3
def ResetH(NewH)
    x= NewH
ResetH(5)
print("x is", x)
```

gives error because you can't merge str and int variables

---

```
 Tags=["ad","cd","Ef","gh"]
 print(tags[1])
```

prints:

```
cd
```